# Show Popover when keydown and keyup on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popover

How Can I **Copy Number entered by the user and show on a Popover** via `javascript` or `jquery`?

I mean when user typed numbers biger than zero, forexample: `1000`, popover Show `1000`.
[image: photo]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //this calculates values automatically 
    getPriceAndPopUp();
    $("#price").on("keydown keyup", function() {
     getPriceAndPopUp();   
    });
});

function getPriceAndPopUp() {
    var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
    if (!isNaN(price) && price > 0) {
        alert(price);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form>
    Price:<br>
    <input type="number" 
      name="price" 
      id="price" 
      class="form-control" 
      min="0" 
      required />
  </form> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the user to finish typing before you show the number, to do that you need to delay the alert show using a timeout function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timeout;
  //this calculates values automatically 
  getPriceAndPopUp();
  $("#price").on("keydown keyup", function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = getPriceAndPopUp();
  });
});

function getPriceAndPopUp() {
  var price = document.getElementById('price').value;

  return setTimeout(function() {

    if (!isNaN(price) && price > 0) {
      $('[data-content]').attr('data-content',price);
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show');
    }
  }, 400);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <form>
    Price:<br>
    <input type="number" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" min="0" required data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="0"/>
  </form>


</body>
```

Comment: then you need a popover library

Comment: `https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_popover_pos&stacked=h` I mean this popup/popover

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on `blur` event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //this calculates values automatically 
  getPriceAndPopUp();
  $("#price").on("blur", function() {
    getPriceAndPopUp();
  });
});

function getPriceAndPopUp() {
  var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
  if (!isNaN(price) && price > 0) {
    alert(price);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form>
    Price:<br>
    <input type="number" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" min="0" required />
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I added a photo to my question, I mean bootstrap popup or a normal popup/popover, if user typed 1, popover show 1, in live typing... if typed 22, popover show 22

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei you can find all the info here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/